# Tengo un div con un texto dentro y quiero que ese texto cambie mientras presiono ctrl y cuando suelto ctrl que vuelva a aparecer el primer texto

Tags: javascript

Tengo un div con un texto dentro y quiero que ese texto cambie mientras presiono ctrl y cuando suelto ctrl que vuelva a aparecer el primer texto.

```
   var div   = document.createElement("div");
    var t     = document.createTextNode("Texto 1");
    divProducto.appendChild(t);
```

Comment: Solicitá [fusionar tus cuentas](/contact) en _Problema de Cuenta_ > _Necesito combinar perfiles de usuario_. Tenés un usuario duplicado...

Comment: Y también [esta pregunta](/q/600862) duplicada.

Comment: Hola Gilbert, bienvenido, te sugiero que elimines la pregunta hecha sin registrar, no suele ser bien recibido, el hacer dos veces la misma pregunta, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!. PD: muestra que has intentado...

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer uso de los eventos [**`keyup`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event) y [**`keydown`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event).

En donde:

- `keyup`: El evento ocurre cuando una tecla se presiona hacia abajo (es decir, antes de que se suelte).
- `keydown`: El evento ocurre cuando una tecla que estaba siendo presionada se suelta (es decir, cuando dejas de presionarla).

Recuerda que para hacer el uso de los eventos, tenemos que utilizar [**`addEventListener`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), quien se encarga de vincular un evento específico a un elemento del DOM. Entonces, la estructura sería el siguiente:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  // ...
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  // ...
});
```

En donde estamos indicando que cuando ocurran los eventos de `keyup` y `keydown` en todo el documento (que sería `document`), se ejecutará una función anónima que recibe dicho evento como parámetro (que es `e`).

> `e` es un objeto que contiene información sobre el evento que ocurrió, en este caso, el evento de presionar o soltar una tecla.

Entonces, cuando ocurran estos eventos, debemos verificar qué tecla se presionó.

Para esto, debemos utilizar a `e.key`, que es una cadena que representa la tecla presionada o soltada. Por ejemplo, si presionas la tecla `A`, `e.key` contendría la cadena "a", y obtendremos ese valor. Por ejemplo, en tu caso que quieres que ocurra algo cuando se presione la tecla `CTRL`, colocamos:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Control") {
    // ...
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Control") {
    // ...
  }
});
```

En donde prácticamente le decimos que cuando se presione la tecla `CTRL`, se ejecuta el primer evento `keyup` y automáticamente ingresa al `if` ya que la tecla presionada es `CTRL`, y al soltar esa tecla `CTRL`, se ejecuta el segundo evento `keydown`. Y dentro de los `if` es donde ocurrirá el cambio del texto de tu `div` al presionar la tecla y soltarla.

#### Demo:

```js
let div = document.getElementById("divProducto");
let texto1 = "Texto 1";
let texto2 = "Texto 2";

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Control") {
    div.textContent = texto1;
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Control") {
    div.textContent = texto2;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="divProducto">Texto 1</div>
```

Comment: Porqué responder preguntas que solicitan "software a medida"?